# My javascript function is working partially/ not working properly

Tags: javascript, html

I have separated files for the HTML and JS code.. I want to make a function which allows me to change the image when I click on it with another (like an array of images(?)) the HTML-JS link is done like this:

```
<script src="file.js"></script>
```

My HTML is here:

`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
    <script src="proiect.js"></script>
 </head>
<body>
    <img src="images/image7.jpg" alt="path not found" class="dynamic-image" onclick="wrapper(1)">
    <img src="images/image10.jpg" alt="path not found" class="dynamic-image" onclick="wrapper(0)">
</body>
</html>
```

`

My JS code:

```
var wrapper = function changeImg(param) {
'use strict';

var preloads=[],c;


function preload(){

    for(c=0;c<arguments.length;c++) {
        preloads[preloads.length]=new Image();
        preloads[preloads.length-1].src=arguments[c];
    }
    c=0;

}
if (param==1){
    preload('src1');
    alert("param=1");}
    if(param==0){
        preload('src2');
        alert("param=0");
    }

    document.getElementsByClassName('dynamic-image').addEventListener('click',
        function() {
            c++;
            if(c==preloads.length) {
                c=0;
            }
            this.src=preloads[c].src;
        });
}
wrapper(param);
```

My problem is that when I click on the image it shows the message (param=1 / param=0), but it won't change the image and I don't understand why ...

Comment: src1, src2 are like so:
"file://C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/foldername/images/0.jpg"

Answer (score 0):

Always put your scripts at the end of your body because your script need to wait that all your ressources are loaded.

Comment: I did it but it is the same :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to do just this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>

 </head>
<body>
    <img src="images/image7.jpg" alt="path not found" class="dynamic-image" onclick="wrapper(1)">
    <img src="images/image10.jpg" alt="path not found" class="dynamic-image" onclick="wrapper(0)">
    <script src="proiect.js"></script> <!-- SCRIPT TAG AT THE END OF BODY TAG -->
</body>
</html>
```

The entire problem is this: when you put your `script` tag in the `head`, your function triggers before the DOM is created... so it executes before the images are even created. The best-practice is to **put your scripts at the end of the body tag.**

Comment: I've tried to do so but it still doesn't work. Could the JS function not be correct? First I used document.getElementById('dynamic-image').addEventListener('click',
        function() {...} (there was only one image with given id) and it worked. But i want to use this function for more images

Answer (score 0):

Your JavaScript file needs to be on the bottom of the page, after all `<img>` tags are loaded.

You can format your HTML as so:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <body>
        <img src="images/image7.jpg" alt="path not found" class="dynamic-image" onclick="wrapper(1)">
        <img src="images/image10.jpg" alt="path not found" class="dynamic-image" onclick="wrapper(0)">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="proiect.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: this is my HTML now:
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
 <img src="images/image7.jpg" alt="path not found" class="dynamic-image" onclick="wrapper(0)">
 <img src="images/image10.jpg" alt="path not found" class="dynamic-image" onclick="wrapper(1)">
 <script src="proiect.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
`
but it still won't change the image when clicked

Comment: @andreixxi Do you have any errors thrown in console?

Comment: actually I do but I don't have the faintest idea what it means
VM291:38 Uncaught ReferenceError: param is not defined
    at <anonymous>:38:10
(anonymous)

Comment: @andreixxi On your onclick, try changing wrapper(param) to changeImg(param)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need your "wrapper(param);" in your proiect.js file because the function is called by the attributes "onclick" of your images.

With the addEventListener function, you can't get the object used, you have to use jquery framework with something like:

```
    var wrapper = function changeImg(param) {
    'use strict';

    var preloads=[],c;


    function preload(){
        for(c=0; c<arguments.length; c++) {
            preloads[preloads.length] = new Image();
            preloads[preloads.length-1].src = arguments[c];
        }
        c=0;
    }
    if (param == 1){
        preload('images/image10.jpg');
        // alert("param=1");
    }
    if(param == 0){
        preload('images/image7.jpg');
        // alert("param=0");
    }

    $('.dynamic-image').on('click', function() {
        c++;
        if(c == preloads.length) {
            c=0;
        }
        console.log(this.src);
        this.src = preloads[c].src;
    });
}
```

And your HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>

 </head>
<body>
    <img src="images/image7.jpg" alt="path not found" class="dynamic-image" onclick="wrapper(1)">
    <img src="images/image10.jpg" alt="path not found" class="dynamic-image" onclick="wrapper(0)">

    <script src="proiect.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And of course add the "jquery.min.js" file in your folder: https://jquery.com/download/

I know that it's not exactly what you want but it can help you ;-)

Comment: thank you so much,I will try to do so shortly! as u saw i am a beginner with javascript.. it is not quite clear for me what a jquery framework is.. could you make a parallel with python/ c++ ?

Comment: Jquery is a javascript framework, it's a tool you can use to simplify your coding. For exemple: here it replace the "document.getElementByClas..." by a simple "$('.dynamic-image')..." If you want to learn more, I think this course can be useful: [openclassrooms/jquery](https://openclassrooms.com/en/courses/3523281-make-javascript-easier-with-jquery)